# General question about pumping lemma statement for regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, pumping-lemma

According to the formal statement of the lemma here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages

It is written at (3) that for all $i≥0, xy^iz∈L$.
Until this moment, I was certain that $i$ must be a natural number.
But what if, for example, $|y|=4$ and I want to pick $i=2.5$. Is that possible to pick an $i$ which is not an integer?
I will get a valid length, and it looks ok by definition, however that seems strange to me that I can perform $y^i$ with an i that isn't an integer.

Comment: $i$ must be a natural number. $y^i$ doesn't make sense for other exponents when $y$ is a string.

Comment: Lets say I have the word $ab$ . why can't I think of  $(ab)^{1.5}$ as $aba$?

Comment: You can, but then $\bigl((ab)^{1.5}\bigr)^2 \neq (ab)^3$. And if the exponent is not a rational number such that $\text{exponent}\cdot \text{length}$ is an integer, what then? $a^{0.5} = c$?

Comment: In addition to exponentiation by not integer is not well defined, the intuition behind the pumping lemma is that for words long enough you are sure to take a loop in the automaton recognizing the language. hence you can iterate or "pump" this loop. Thus taking the loop 2.5 times does not preserve the property since you will be left in the middle of the loop and don't know what to do ...

Answer (score 0):

You are right; $i$ must be a natural number.

It is quite often the case in mathematical writing that there are implicit assumptions. The reader is then supposed to know them or infer them from the context. In this case, you - the OP - in fact did know that $i$ was supposed to be a natural number :-).